# ActiveRecord query across three models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have three models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :projects, :through => :permissions

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project
 belongs_to :role

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, :through => :permissions
```

It's very easy with the above to get all of a Project's users: `@project.users`

But what I want to do is get something like this: Get all the Users in all of the user's projects.

So if a user has 3 projects, each with 5 users. I want to query to get all 15 users across all of the user's groups.

I'm trying that with.

```
 current_user.projects.users
```

but Rails isn't liking that much. current_user.projects works great, but not users.

Suggestions? Ideas? thanks!

**UPDATED CODE 3 based on noodl's comments**

```
  scope :suggestedContacts, lambda { |user|
    users_from_projects = user.projects.reduce([]) {|all_users,prj|
      all_users + prj.users
    }.uniq
  }
```

**ERRORS:**

NoMethodError (undefined method `includes_values' for #):

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My two solutions are:

- **clean**, simple standard rails meta-code, no custom finders
- **efficient**, fetches in one SQL query, no N+1 issues
- **compliant**, meaning you can still build, create etc. on the relation

#### 1.

You can chain your relation in the user class.
As rails 3.0.x does not yet support nested has_many_through you can use [this](https://github.com/releod/nested_has_many_through) plugin until rails 3.1

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :permissions
 has_many :projects, :through => :permissions
 has_many :users_in_projects, :through => :projects, :source => :user # chain the relation

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, :through => :permissions

current_user.users_in_projects
```

#### 2.

Another way would be to eager load and reduce (like the other answers have already described, but I'll make it more explicit).
This is more work, less dependencies.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :permissions
 has_many :projects, :through => :permissions, :include => :users # eager load users

class Permission < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :project

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :users, :through => :permissions

current_user.projects.map(&:users).reduce(&:+).uniq_by(&:id) 
# returns users in current_user's projects, one query, some computations
```

Answer (score 2):

@noodl has the right idea, but yes it does cause "some" overhead. Granted unless you're talking about having millions of projects and permissions, you won't notice much of an improvement by optimizing. Regardless, here is an alternative approach which in theory, though not pretty, gives you what you want "efficiently" (assuming your tables are indexed properly).

```
class User

  has_many :project_users, :class_name => "User", :finder_sql => 'select u.* from users u join permissions pp on pp.user_id=u.id join projects p on pp.project_id=p.id where project_id in (select project_id from permissions pp2 where user_id=#{id}) and pp.user_id != #{id} group by u.id'

end
```

It's not a scope, but does allow you to say:

```
user = User.find(1)
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Stephen">
user.project_users
=> [#<User id: 2, name: "Kathleen">, #<User id: 3, name: "Anne">]
```

Comment: Interesting new idea. Just gave it a try but got back "StatementInvalid: PGError: ERROR:  column "u.email" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Comment: If I remove the group it works. is there a way to just say get all unique users? Or I should say DISTINCT :)

Comment: I changed it to: "finder_sql => 'select DISTINCT u.* from....: and that did the trick. Thoughts?

Comment: Can you tell me how you modified the SQL? The group by is on u.id so unless you modified the select users.* there shouldn't be an issue unless PG has some weird logic going on (I'm testing with MySQL)

Comment: I'll be honest, I only ever use DISTINCT for one column distinction, I know that it processes entire rows, but I don't know how the internals work or where it stops. Would be nice if it stops at the PK in this case rather than trying to analyze the entire row. Someone else would probably have a much better answer for that ;)

Comment: That's super cool @jenjenut. Now I'm sad I've only one vote >:-(

Answer (score 1):

Since the comment threads are getting a little laboured I'll try and spell out how I'd solve it directly.

```
users = current_user.projects.map(&:users).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: This would work but cause a [N+1 queries problem as described here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) And see, no down vote because this is a related answer even though I believe it isn't the best one :)

Comment: Thanks but can this be turned into a scope? Something like:   scope :suggestedContacts2, lambda { |user|
    user.projects.map(&:users).flatten.uniq
  }

Comment: The reason for wanting a scope is I need to populate a list of users based on 3 conditions and am thinking about doing a 3 chained scopes with a limit at the end.

Comment: @edgerunner: Yes, good point. I'm always getting bitten by that O(N+1) thing. Feel free to combine my answer with yours and I'll delete this one.

Comment: It would make sense to define a scope but doing it that way still has the N+1 queries problem. It would work but would degrade performance.

Comment: @noodl, I think we should keep this in any case. It is a valid answer and makes for good discussion and learning.

Comment: I don't believe my code fits in to the context of a scope. For one thing you couldn't call it on the class as a whole and also it doesn't actually return a scope so wouldn't be chainable. On the other hand if you just need to parameterise the query based on some conditions, just add it to a method definition and deal with the parameters there.

Comment: Alright thanks ,but it looks like based on the above this won't work. Still hoping to get this figured out, going tofocus on edgerunner's method

Comment: So you want your user's projects' users. Fun with apostrophes :-)

Comment: Although this has O(N+1) issues that N is only the number of projects the user has, as far as I can work out. That's presumably not a very big N for your big-O.

Answer (score 0):

Since projects is an aggregate, it's going to return Enumerable objects. You can iterate across them using (for example) each:

```
current_user.projects.each {|prj|
  prj.users.each{|usr|
    #do stuff
  }
}
```

If you want to collect these together into one enumerable (and get rid of repeats), then

```
users_from_projects = current_user.projects.reduce([]) {|all_users,prj|
  all_users = all_users + prj.users
}.uniq
```

EDIT to correct, thanks for pointing it out noodl.

Comment: Your reduce (inject) call needs an array seed argument. `.reduce([]) {...`. Also the block should probably be `all_users + prj.users`.

Comment: impressive. Thanks made rais angry 'NameError (undefined local variable or method `users' for #<Class:0x105697ae8>):"  I turned you code into a scope in the model as so:   scope :suggestedContacts2, lambda { |user|
  users_from_projects = user.projects.reduce {|all_users,prj|
    all_users = users + prj.users
  }.uniq
}

Comment: Noodl, tried your suggestion, stilli errors with "NameError (undefined local variable or method `users' for #<Class:0x105d70c70>):", I'll update with the current code above in the ques. thanks the help

Comment: I get the following "NoMethodError (undefined method `includes_values' for #<Array:0x1054d3608>):" when I update it to just all_users = prj.users  tried that because I don't see where users is coming from?

Comment: @AnApprentice: then you didn't try my suggestion :) The point is that @wilsona's code refers to a "users" local variable where no such thing exists (as far as I can see).

Comment: Thanks noodl. code updated and the code snippet has been added to the question above. Did I implement your suggestion correctly?

Answer (score 0):

To your User class add:

```
 has_many :users, :through => :permissions
```

So it will look like:

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects, :through => :permissions
   has_many :users, :through => :permissions
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to [eager-load your associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html)

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects, :through => :permissions, :include => :users
  has_many :permissions, :include => {:project => :users}
  …
end
```

Comment: Thanks, that's simpler but still errors, >> @user.projects.users
NoMethodError: undefined method `users' for #<Class:0x1005156c0>

Comment: I assumed you had it in there but I guess you also need to add a `has_many :permissions` to both models as well

Comment: Why all the down votes? What am I missing? I'm trying to learn here :)

Comment: May I ask about the downvoting? It is rude to downvote without giving a reason.

Comment: I stick up for those that help me! maybe an xwife? :)

Comment: Beats me, looks like I'm under attack by some vengeful spirit. :)

Comment: I downvoted because I believe your answer is unhelpful. The OP is asking how to get the results of has-many-through-many, in a sense, and no amount of :include-ing is going to help with that. I'll be happy to be proved wrong though :-)

Comment: @noodl, down votes are good for malformed, totally unrelated or as you put it, unhelpful answers. An answer that "may not work for this case" is not a good candidate for a down vote. I'd say my answer is related to the problem and worth trying(even if it doesn't work) and from your tone I understand that you didn't try it yourself.

Comment: Also, I downvoted before you added the second `has_many` line. At that point your answer made very little sense, to me.

Comment: Nice to get along :) That leaves two downvoters in the shadows. Come out and play.

Comment: so is this now the way to go?

Comment: Alright edgerunner, just gave this a go, but Rails error'd with "stack level too deep"

Comment: The logs show queries going crazy for projects and permissions.

Comment: I figured that after reading some documentation. Probably put you in an infinite loop because it starts with a user and ends with a user. Trying to figure out a solution now :)

Comment: Thanks Edgerunner! I had no idea what I was getting into with this one

Comment: Turned out to be a tough nut, isn't it :)